# Can I use iPhone VoiceOver in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

For an accessibility task I need to test the iPhone VoiceOver, but since I don't have an iPhone is it possible to turn it on in a simulated device in Xcode somehow?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to **test VoiceOver with Xcode** in a simulated device is using the **[Accessibility Inspector](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-16407.html)** tool.

It will display a11y information about each accessible element in your app to examine the information they provide but this tool won't spell out anything.

The `Accessibility Inspector` is very helpful for testing the a11y during development but it can't replace a physical device for testing your app with VoiceOver reading out your element labels.

I strongly recommend to take a look at [this detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2019/#accessibility-inspector) about the **Xcode 11 new features** dealing with the `Accessibility Inspector` that vocalizes and selects elements on the simulator after showing the way to get the complete description of a graphic element in conjunction with its selections.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Accessibility Inspector]

You can use the accessibility inspector built into Xcode like this, obviously it doesn't work exactly the same as on a physical device, but it's always a way to partially test your app on a simulator

URL of screenshot:
https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2016/407/#accessibility-inspector-0938

Answer (score 2):

Launch the sim, then from Xcode:

- Menu > Xcode > Open developer tool > Accessibility inspector
- Click the target/reticle icon in the inspector window, then click on the simulator somewhere.
- Then click the speech bubble in the inspector window.

Works for me in Xcode 14 :)